# What is the quickest way to get an airship rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, airship

I already have private pilot for single engine land with instrument and commercial ratings.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: [AOPA: What it takes to become a blimp pilot](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2013/september/04/what-it-takes-to-become-a-blimp-pilot)

Comment: @Pondlife I reside in NJ, USA  and my base airport is 47N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the type of Airship you're looking to get a rating in, I found a [Flight Standardization Board (FSB) Report](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/fsb/lz-n07-100_r1.htm) for a Zeppelin, that discusses the training required for that specific Airship.

Here is the relevant time requirements for this particular airship from the document:

```
5.2 Commercial Airship Pilot
(a) Ab Initio:
Standard duration of training: Approximately 20 months
Maximum duration of training: 24 months
Theoretical training: 300 hours
Practical training: Three months on a ground crew 
Minimum of 50 training flight hours
Minimum of 150 supervised flight hours  

(b) Students holding a CPL:
Standard duration of training: Approximately 15 months
Maximum duration of training: N/A
Theoretical training: Minimum of 93 hours
Practical training: Three months on a ground crew
Minimum of 40 training flight hours
Minimum of 130 supervised flight hours  

(c) Type Rating:
Standard duration of training: Approximately four months
Maximum duration of training: N/A
Theoretical training: Minimum of 49 hours
Practical training: Minimum of 25 training flight hours
Minimum of 100 supervised flight hours
```

The Commercial Practical Test Standards for Lighter-than-Air can be found on the [FAA Website](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-18.pdf), and you would need to make sure that you had satisfied the following conditions:

> An applicant already holding a commercial pilot certificate who
>   applies for an additional category and/or class rating on that
>   certificate must:
>
> 1. hold a commercial pilot certificate;
> 2. have the prescribed aeronautical experience and training required for the category and class rating sought;
> 3. pass an additional knowledge test for the rating sought (unless already rated in airplane, rotorcraft, or airship) since the beginning
>      of the 24th month before the month in which he/she takes the practical
>      test; and
> 4. obtain an endorsement from an authorized instructor certifying that the applicant has been given flight instruction in the applicable
>      AREAS OF OPERATION listed in 14 CFR part 61, section 61.127, for the
>      commercial pilot rating sought in preparation for the practical test
>      within 60 days preceding the date of application. The statement shall
>      also state that the instructor finds the applicant competent to pass
>      the practical test, and that the applicant has satisfactory knowledge
>      of the subject area(s) in which a deficiency was indicated on the
>      knowledge test report.

So you can see the standard duration of training is approximately 15 months. There are some interesting anecdotes [in this article from AOPA](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2013/september/04/what-it-takes-to-become-a-blimp-pilot):

> Pilots interested in getting their pilot certificate with an airship
>   rating will have to train while on the job, since there are no schools
>   that teach this particular skill, according to Bret Viets, chief pilot
>   on the MetLife Snoopy Two blimp.

Veits goes on to say that it **took him 66 days**. (He started Dec 4, 2007 and took his checkride on Feb 8, 2008). And he thought he did in a pretty short time period. It sounds like he got lucky and ended up having the airship to himself for training for a couple weeks!

Looks like you're on your way with a commercial rating, too:

> The company prefers that applicants have a commercial rating, whether
>   it’s on airplanes, helicopters, gliders, or hot air balloons, said
>   Viets. “It just makes the transition to airship hourly requirements
>   less if someone already has a commercial rating,” he said. “To
>   transition to airships is a minimum of 50 hours, but it usually takes
>   a little longer than that, like any aircraft rating.”
>
> If an applicant does not have a commercial rating, he or she will need
>   250 hours in airships before getting that commercial airship rating,
>   said Viets. “They prefer pilots with 1,200 hours and a CFI
>   certificate,” he said.

Comment: Another (more recent) anecdote: Embry-Riddle's Alumni Magazine _Lift_ had a feature in the Fall 2017 Edition (https://lift.erau.edu/flying-into-the-wind/) where an Alumnus mentioned that it took him *9 months* to earn his Airship rating.